# Dynamic Height with CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am doing a comment page. I have a json with all the comments, this comments go in one bubble speech. The problem is the comments can varied their size, and I want to have the bubble speech according to the size of the comment.
An example

[image]

As you can see the top of the bubble speech are not align. Here is the demo: http://jsbin.com/uLuvaWU/1.

I decided to make the change to dynamic because I was having a lot of white space in some bubble speech. Example: http://jsbin.com/OrIWAr

Not sure what I have to change from my CSS

```
.bubble-panel {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px dotted #CCCCCC;
    height: 350px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 20px;
}


.bubble 
{
position: relative;
width: 350px;
height: auto;
padding: 4px;
background: #FFFFFF;
-webkit-border-radius: 31px;
-moz-border-radius: 31px;
border-radius: 31px;
border: #46A5E4 solid 9px;
display:inline-block;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-right: 50px;
vertical-align: middle; /* ADD THIS LINE */
}

.bubble p
{
    margin: 10px;
}

.bubble:after 
{
content: '';
position: absolute;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 31px 14px 0;
border-color: #FFFFFF transparent;
display: block;
width: 0;
z-index: 1;
margin-left: -14px;
bottom: -31px;
left: 20%;
}

.bubble:before 
{
content: '';
position: absolute;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 39px 22px 0;
border-color: #46A5E4 transparent;
display: block;
width: 0;
z-index: 0;
margin-left: -22px;
bottom: -48px;
left: 20%;
}
.caption {
    //border: 1px solid red;
    width: 20em;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: auto;
    right: 0px;
}
.caption h1, .caption h2, .caption h3 {
    font-size: 1.00em;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have changed a bit the class `.bubble-panel` on your CSS.
(http://jsbin.com/uLuvaWU/2)

```
 .bubble-panel {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px dotted #CCC;
    height: 350px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 20px;
    top: 0;
    float: left;
  }
```

Tested on Chrome, Firefox and Safari and top of the bubble speechs are now aligned.